# Inputting files in different folders as arguments to ffmpeg in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm working on a program using ffmpeg in Python and I'm trying to stack a bunch of PNG images into a video.  I want to keep the code on my Dropbox but use the local hard drive to do the work, so I when I input the files as arguments, I want to include the directory.  The code below makes the raw input file just fine, but when I try to begin a pipe with ffmpeg, it tells me it can't find the input file.  Is there some special way to format this if the input file is in a different directory?  I've had similar code work fine with the files all located in the same folder.  Thanks!

```
import subprocess as sp

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import os
import shutil

import tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog

FFMPEG_BIN = 'ffmpeg.exe'

def readImages(pathToImages):
    filenames = os.listdir(path=pathToImages)
    f = open("C:\\Users\johnwstanford\Desktop\outputfile.raw", "wb")

    for file in filenames:
        print(file)
        image = plt.imread(pathToImages + '/' + file)
        image = np.delete(image, 3, 2)*255

        f.write(image.tobytes())
    f.close()

readImages(tkFileDialog.askdirectory())

command2 = [FFMPEG_BIN,
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-s', '1600x1200',
           '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
           '-r', '25',
           '-i', "C:\\Users\johnwstanford\Desktop\outputfile.raw",
           "C:\\Users\johnwstanford\Desktop\output.mp4"]

pipe2 = sp.Popen(command2, stdin = sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
print(pipe2.communicate()[1])
pipe2.kill()
os.remove("C:\\Users\johnwstanford\Desktop\outputfile.raw")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the `\` in the paths properly:

Use

```
"C:\\Users\\johnwstanford\\Desktop\\outputfile.raw"
```

or

```
r"C:\Users\johnwstanford\Desktop\outputfile.raw"
```

The same changes are needed for the `output.mp4` file.

You can also try to use slashes instead of backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I messed with it some more and finally figured out that it's talking about being unable to find the binary.  I added the path to the binary and it seems to work now.